# How a newly created anaconda environment has already all the libraries installed in it?

Tags: python, anaconda

created a new env in anaconda. My expectation was that I would only be able to use packages in this env that were installed by default while creating env in anaconda prompt and had to install other libraries like pandas, matplotlib and many more. However, I am able to use all packages that were installed in the Base environment without installing them in the new env.

But when on running 'conda list env_name in command, it only shows the pre installed libraries not all.

Could somebody explain what I'm misunderstanding here? And from where the new env inherits all the libraries? is this to do with path mentioned in environment variable.

did a lot of research but not getting an accurate answer. need a good explanation. Thanks in advance!CHEERS!!

Comment: Did you activate the new environment?

Comment: yes i did and opened jupyter notebook as well. And on running the code for ex: import pandas as pd, it should have thrown an error 'module not found' but it was ran successfully.

Comment: Yep, happens the same to me. Had opencv installed before even installing anaconda3. I installed conda, created an env (just with a name, nothing else), run python3 and import cv2, and it ran... I've worked with venvs for some time and this has never happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" with Anaconda is that you first need to activate an environment before can actually use it:

```
conda activate env_name
```

Afterwards you'll only have access to the packages that have been installed into this environment.

Comment: i activated the environment but opened jupyter notebook as well. And on running the code for ex: import pandas as pd, it should have thrown an error 'module not found' but it ran successfully.

Comment: And which kernel is Jupyter Notebook using (see upper right)? Jupyter basically manages the environments itself.

Comment: Kernel show Python3. Is this related with the Environment variable path. Whenever create a new environment it will automatically inherit the libraries from the path defined in environment variable.

Comment: Python3 is your base environment and adding it's python.exe to the path is not the default option on Anaconda installation and actually not recommended. Now you see why.